# Android multi color.xml selection

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme

Suppose I have defined two themes in my App: AppTheme.Blue and AppTheme.Green, and correspondingly, I would like have set of color, thus I could apply it according two different theme.

For example, when I call `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_primary);` under `AppTheme.Green` it will return a green color as `?attr/colorPrimary` but Blue if under `AppTheme.Blue`, thus the the widget will always be the same color as title bar.

How can I define those two set of colors thus is system will choose it dynamically according to the current theme adopted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I got, you are talking about using multiple theme. Here is a scenario for your question.

Define two themes in styles.xml

Theme Blue:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_blue</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/primaryColorDark_blue</item>
    </style>
```

Theme Green:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Green" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark_green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryAccent_green</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/primaryColorDark_green</item>
</style>
```

Define all the colors in color.xml accordingly

Add the following code to Get the Primary Color of the selected theme and set it to your widget.

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = this.getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary, typedValue, true);
TypedArray arr =
        this.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[]{
                android.R.attr.colorPrimary});
int primaryColor = arr.getColor(0, -1);
yourTextView.setTextColor(primaryColor);  //ex
arr.recycle();
```

If your selected theme is Blue then the textcolor will be blue as well. Hope this suffices.

Comment: That seems to be a  nice solution, thank you at first. And I also have a question is that is there great efficiency loss with the usage of `obtainStyledAttributes` , you know, if so, I'd better to create a Hashmap or something else as cache of these colors.

Comment: As far as you are recycling your TypedArray, it shouldn't be a problem